# How to join lines adding a separator?

Tags: regex, join, vim, lines, separator

The command `J` joins lines.
The command `gJ` joins lines removing spaces

Is there also a command to Join lines adding a separator between the lines?

Example:

**Input**:

```
text
other text
more text
text
```

What I want to do:
- select these 4 lines
- if there are spaces at start and/or EOL remove them
- join lines adding a separator '//' between them

**Output**:

```
text//other text//more text//text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:substitute` for that, matching on `\n`:

```
:%s#\s*\n\s*#//#g
```

However, this appends the separator at the end, too (because the last line in the range also has a newline). You could remove that manually, or specify the `c` flag and quit the substitution before the last one, or reduce the range by one and `:join` the last one instead:

```
:1,$-1s#\s*\n\s*#//#g|join
```

Comment: +1 - I was trying something like `1,$-1norm A//|join` but somehow that doesn't work. It appends the join to? Do you happen to know why? Is it because the normal command? *(note: there's an escape between // and | but it got lost in the comment)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: You need to wrap the `:norm A` in `:execute`; cp. `:h :bar`

Comment: Wow beautiful solution. Thank you Ingo.

Comment: @Remonn, I used `#` to avoid having to escape the `//` replacement as `\/\/`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin "**Join**", could do what you wanted, and more.

https://github.com/sk1418/Join

Except for all features provided by the build-in `:join` command, **Join** can:

```
Join lines with separator (string)
Join lines with or without trimming the leading/trailing whitespaces
Join lines with negative count (backwards join)
Join lines in reverse
Join lines and keep joined lines (without removing joined lines)
Join lines with any combinations of above options
```

check the homepage for details and examples/screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do it, but I would recommend going by simplest route possible - recording a macro or doing multi-step command, for example by:

Appending to all lines excluding last by

- Using substitution (`:1,$-1s#$#//#`)
- Appending (`:1,$-1norm A//`)

And then join using visual selection (`vGgJ`) or by any other method.

Unless you're doing this operation very often you most likely forget any complex commands or existence of specialized plugin in your config, thus my recommendation of using generic, often used sub steps.

Answer (score 1):

Another substitution, for the sake of diversity:

```
:%s:\n\ze.://
```

Answer (score 1):

Will list 50 items per line seperated by spaces:

`seq 0 70 | xargs -L 50 | sed 's/ /,/g'`

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70
```