# zip iterator missing last elements how to join lines together

Tags: python, bash

How can I join all lines together without missing the last elements.

`zip()` seems to be missing the last elements in this stream.

For example: `seq 0 70 | xargs -L 50 | sed 's/ /,/g'`

Input:

```
seq 0 70 | python -c $'import sys\nfor x in zip(*[iter(sys.stdin)]*50): print(",".join(x).replace("\\n",""))\n'
```

Wrong Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
```

Expected 50 items per line and last zip contains the rest:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69
```

Related:

- [sed join lines together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852132/sed-join-lines-together)
- [How to join lines adding a separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201302/how-to-join-lines-adding-a-separator)
- [Python join data lines together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786091/python-join-data-lines-together)

Comment: `zip` stops on the shortest iterable. An option is to use `izip_longest` with `None`s padded for the shorter iterables (or pass a `fillvalue` to override `None`). A better alternative however is to use a better grouper recipe. With some modification, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063403/3125566

Comment: @MosesKoledoye how does that work between unix pipes, and as a unix one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $'import sys,itertools\nfor x in itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(sys.stdin)]*50): print(",".join(x).replace("\\n",""))\n'
```

maybe?  this uses izip_longest to not drop extra items at the end

Comment: Yes thanks. One change on the inside `",".join(x)`  x should be  `[y for y in x if y]` otherwise it results in `expected string, NoneType found`

Comment: `[y for y in x if y]` can just be `list(x)`